# How can I replace constructor injection in decorators, with method injection to get chaining and have existing code work as is?

Tags: java

We have code that looks like this:

```
Service<E,F> pipeline = new MyServiceDecorator2(new MyServiceDecorator1(new MyService()));
```

This is then executed as `F f = pipeline.apply(new E("E"))`

We'd like this to read something like:

```
Service<A,B> myService = new MyService();
// Service<C,D>
MyServiceDecorator1 myServiceDecorator1 = new MyServiceDecorator1();
// Service<E,F>
MyServiceDecorator2 myServiceDecorator2 = new MyServiceDecorator2();

Service<E,F> pipeline = myServiceDecorator2.andThen(myServiceDecorator1).andThen(myService);

// This should still be doable i.e., the end goal
F f = pipeline.apply(new E("E"));
```

We've tried various tricks but we can't get the return  types to line up correctly. The above would throw an error - we just added `andThen` to each Decorator class manually just to understand the flow, like so:

```
public <J,K> Service andThen(Service<J,K> next) {
 this.service = next;
 return next;
}
```

This returns the type of the "next item" in the *chain*. I tried some tricks with `next/prev` references/pointers to go up the chain but nothing seems to work. Is this even possible?

Here's a [REPL](https://repl.it/repls/ClumsyThoughtfulScientist) showing the code with a print statement showing progression through the decorators.

**Context:** We have a fair amount of code that can be simplified into "decorators" to implement the "pipe and filter" pattern so that we can provide a basic "framework" to allow developers to apply the same pattern/thinking to solve the same problem vs. copy/pasta or reinventing the wheel. The above is an "example" of what we intend to achieve. We plan to convert this into generics, but for now, there's duplicate code.

Comment: Looking at your example (REPL) I see the decorated services are "fixed". Is that ywhat you want? A Decorator is able to decorate a specific Service. Right?

Comment: Can apply accept a Domain and not a specific type?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: *working on another approach (I think it has the same issue...)*

Well, you cannot really obtain what you want, you need to tradeoff on something.
In this case it is on the `apply` method, which has to accept a `Domain`.

This happens because the *wrapped* `Service` isn't set at construction time, and so it cannot be 100% typed.

```
interface Service<A extends Domain, B extends Domain> {
    B apply(final Domain a);
    Service<A, B> andThen(final Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> service);
}
```

---

```
class MyService implements Service<A, B> {
    private Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> wrapped;

    @Override
    public B apply(final Domain a) {
        return new B(a.name + "->B");
    }

    @Override
    public Service<A, B> andThen(final Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyServiceDecorator1 implements Service<C, D> {
    private Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> wrapped;

    @Override
    public D apply(final Domain input) {
        // C->A
        Domain a = new A(input.name + "->A");
        // get B
        Domain b = this.wrapped.apply(a);
        // B->D
        return new D(b.name + "->D");
    }

    public Service<C, D> andThen(final Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

```
class MyServiceDecorator2 implements Service<E, F> {
    private Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> wrapped;

    @Override
    public F apply(final Domain input) {
        // E->C
        Domain c = new C(input.name + "->C");
        // get D
        Domain d = this.wrapped.apply(c);
        // D->F
        return new F(d.name + "->F");
    }

    @Override
    public Service<E, F> andThen(final Service<? extends Domain, ? extends Domain> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Service<A, B> myService = new MyService();
    MyServiceDecorator1 myServiceDecorator1 = new MyServiceDecorator1();
    MyServiceDecorator2 myServiceDecorator2 = new MyServiceDecorator2();

    final Service<E, F> efService =
            myServiceDecorator2.andThen(myServiceDecorator1)
                               .andThen(myService);

    // This should still be doable i.e., the end goal
    F f = efService.apply(new E("E"));
    System.out.println(f.name);
}
```

I couldn't do any better, as Java is limited on generics capabilities.

---

Closing words: bytecode generation is your friend.

Comment: This is interesting and useful. Sincerely appreciate the effort. The tradeoff isn't too bad though and my Java Generics isn't the best, especially after a long hiatus!

Comment: @PhD I think my other approach is a dead end. I'm too tired now, but I'll give a shot at it better tomorrow. Question, each decorator accepts a specific type of service, right? Not a generic one, because then it would be impossible to maintain type-safety in a decent manner.

Comment: That is correct. A service is always of type `Service` interface like you posted above - Don't worry too much about it. Rest up :)

At the "concrete level" each decorator accepts a known type. The idea is to make that parameterized somehow with/without generics to make it reusable - but if it's not doable, then may need to go back to the drawing board

Comment: @PhD thanks. It's an interesting problem so I'll give it another try ;)